# CSS background color surround the text

Tags: html, css

I have some multi-line text inside div, can I surround the text with background color which size that is changed according to the text?

```css
.multiline{
  padding:0px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 100px;
  width: ;
  margein:0px
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#FFD382;" align="left" class="multiline">
  Peter
  How are you
  2016-8-10
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div align="left" class="multiline">
   <span style="background-color:#FFD382;">Peter<br/>How are you<br/>2016-8-10</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the text to an [inline-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). So you can set the `background-color` of the text and the `background-color` of the surrounding area.

**See the following example:**

```css
.multiline {
  padding:0px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  height: 100px;
  margin:0px
}
span {
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#FFD382;" align="left" class="multiline">
  <span>Peter
  How are you
  2016-8-10</span>
</div>
```

**You can use your actual solution too by adding `display:inline` to `.multiline`**

```css
.multiline {
  display:inline;
  padding:0px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#FFD382;" align="left" class="multiline">
  Peter
  How are you
  2016-8-10
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I surround the text with background color which size that is changed according to the text ?

Assuming that you can't (or don't wish to) put the text in it's own inline element to which a background can be applied then you have limited options.

The only option I can think of that would apply any sort of background color to the **text** alone, is `text-shadow` and you would need multiple shadows.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zunj3dmn/)

```css
  .multiline
{
  padding:0px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 100px;
  width: ;
  margin:0px;
  text-shadow: 
  0 0 1px green,
  0 0 2px green,
  0 0 3px green,
  0 0 4px green,
  0 0 5px green,
  0 0 6px green,
  0 0 7px green,
  0 0 8px green,
  0 0 9px green;
  }
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#FFD382;" align="left" class="multiline">
         Peter 
         How are you 
         2016-8-10
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `span` instead of `div` and `pre-line` instead of `pre-wrap`

```css
.multiline {
  padding: 0px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<span style="background-color:#FFD382;" class="multiline">
 Peter
 How are you
 2016-8-10
</span>
```